# Why did Gitlab CI gave Error: Cannot find module './node-modules-paths'?

Tags: javascript, docker, gitlab-ci

I got this error on my pipeline

```
> react-scripts build && cp .htaccess build/
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module './node-modules-paths'
```

I logged in to server

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    164 Nov 25  2020 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    827 May 23 11:00 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 node node   2101 Oct 26  2020 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root   4096 May 24 12:06 build
-rw-r--r--    1 root root    192 Jan 11  2021 debug.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     95 May 23 11:04 docker-entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   4096 May 19 10:23 nginx
drwxr-xr-x 1176 node node  36864 May 24 12:04 node_modules
```

I am adding logs from my Docker container

```
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.16
3 info using node@v14.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~prebuild: fluffa-frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: fluffa-frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/fluffa.mykomp/fe/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: CWD: /var/www/html/fluffa.mykomp/fe
10 silly lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build && cp .htaccess build/' ]
11 silly lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle fluffa-frontend@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: fluffa-frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build && cp .htaccess build/`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid fluffa-frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/fluffa.mykomp/fe
16 verbose Linux 4.9.0-18-amd64
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.16
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
```

How it comes it can not find node_modules?
Where path should be specified?

Comment: Carefully read the error `Error: Cannot find module './node-modules-paths'`, it's not about the `node_modules` folder

Comment: It looks like somewhere the `./node-modules-paths.js` script is required, but cannot be found. However your question lacks more debugging information

Comment: @JSONDerulo Iadded logs ,can you take a look?

Comment: Search your codebase for 'node-modules-paths'. Update your question to include what you find.